# modifiying nested redux state without mutating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, dynamic-arrays

Am i Mutating redux state with this function ?

```
function addDefinition(object, payload) {
    var newObject = Object.assign({}, object);
    if(!newObject[payload.guid]){
    newObject[payload.guid] = [];
    }
    newObject[payload.guid].push(payload);
    return newObject;
}
```

I want to create structure to hold data related to different part of application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that `.push()` statement *is* mutating in the later calls.  In the first call, the array is newly created, so it doesn't qualify as a mutation.  In a later call, you've created a new object but copied the existing array reference, so `.push()` mutates the existing array.

Comment: Would he be mutating the existing array even though he made a copy of it in newObject?

Comment: If `object` is the result from last time, and it already contains an array for this `payload.guid` value, then `newObject` will contain _the same reference to the same array_.

Comment: Aw yes, I see it now on MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign. See warning for deep clone) The Object.assign operator does not do deep clones, for that you would need to nest the Object.assign method. Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. See markerikson's answer. Keep in mind you could avoid this with the spread operator.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  guid: []
}

function addDefinition(state = INITIAL_STATE, payload) {

  return {...state, guid: [...state.guid, payload]};

}
```

In addition you could avoid the if statement with initial state.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I have initial state but i want to create nested object with dynamic keys(guid which are inside payload). I am having trouble with spread operator as it always returns undefined or null error.

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: []
}

what i want to achieve is 

data:{
guid1:[ id1:payload1, id2:payload2],
guid2:[ id1:payload1, id4:payload4],
guid3:[ id3:payload3, id4:payload4]
}

Can you tell me how can achieve that with spread operator. its array inside object which cotains object with id. sorry if its hard to read in comment

Comment: I would love to answer your question, but if you could, please mark an answer for this question as accepted and ask it as a new question. Thanks!